# WordPress Site with JQuery filter (Search Filter Pro) slow when many results - How can I speed it up?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, performance, filter

**CONTEXT**

I've used the Search Filter Pro plugin to filter a list of resources by category on [this WordPress page](http://coachingourselves.com/all-modules/).

**PROBLEM**

With a short list of modules, this works just fine - however, as the number of modules is increased, so is the loading time (upwards of 8seconds on some filter requests). The total size of the page is only 1.2mb so I don't think this is the issue. According to [this Pingdom Speed Test](http://fpt.pingdom.com#!/fjHH4/http://coachingourselves.com/all-modules/), a majority of the loading time is spent "waiting":

[image: Pingdom Speed Test]

Any idea why this is happening? Is there anything I can do to speed this up?